# I have a table and why my center cell is longer than others

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project in which I have to make a webpage. I have a table and when I run the code, the center cell is longer than the other cells.

```css
table,td,tr{border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<!document html> 
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>calculatoer</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<div>
<table>
<tr><th>ali</th><th>mohammad</th></tr>
<tr><td>s</td><td>s</td><td>s</td></tr>
<tr><td>s</td><td>s</td><td>s</td></tr>
<tr><td>s</td><td>s</td><td>s</td></tr>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because of center `th` - mohammad. the center td width is same as the center th width. And as you see, min width of center th is bigger than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following code to the existing code:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed ;width: 100% ;">
<td style="width: 25% ;">
```

Comment: can i increase width of td

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ensuring the header matches the number of columns via colspan you can fix the width by a percentage or a specific size using the td CSS class.

```css
table,td,tr{border: 1px solid red; }
td
{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!document html> 
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title>calculatoer</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<div>
<table>
<tr><th colspan="3">ali mohammad</th></tr>
<tr><td>s</td><td>s</td><td>s</td></tr>
<tr><td>s</td><td>s</td><td>s</td></tr>
<tr><td>s</td><td>s</td><td>s</td></tr>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```